# How do I include newlines in a search in less?

Tags: regex, less

How can I search for newlines (or end of lines) as part of a search using less?

For example, I'd like to search for `length=9\n`, but don't want to merely search for `length=9` because that'd get matches for `length=90\n`.

I'm using GNU bash, version 4.0.33(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) on Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic Koala)

I tried reading the friendly manual, but it said

> ```
> /pattern
> ```
>
> Search  forward  in the file for the N-th line containing the
> pattern.  N defaults to 1.  The
> pattern is a regular expression, as
> recognized by the regular expression
> library supplied by your system.  The search starts at the second line displayed
> (but see the -a and -j options, which
> change this).

and I don't know how to RTFM beyond that.

Comment: You might also find searches anchored to word boundaries to be useful. `/\<length=9\>` will find "length=9" that's anywhere on a line without matching "length=90" or "stringlength=9". See `man 7 regex` and `man grep` for more.

Comment: For those looking for an answer to the question's title: I don't believe you can include newlines in a search in less. This means that multiline searches in less do not appear to be possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do:

```
/pattern$
```

The pattern replacing `pattern`, but the `$` must stay, it tells the search to look for the pattern, and then the end of the line.

So you'd do:

```
/length=9$
```