# How to do a multiline search in less?

Tags: gnu, less

In `less`, can you search using <kbd>/</kbd> for a pattern that contains a carriage return and newline? I know your pattern can end with a line using `$` (from [How do I include newlines in a search in less?](https://superuser.com/questions/223848/how-do-i-include-newlines-in-a-search-in-less/223850)), but I need the pattern to match text that spans multiple lines.

I tried `\n`, but that only searches for the `n` character.

Comment: Have you tried `\n+` for 1 or more newlines?

Comment: Which Linux distribution, and do you have defined the environment variable "LESS" ?

Comment: @harrymc How would that help with multiline search?

Comment: Gathering information.

Comment: I fear the answer for less must be no, but if you are looking for other ways to search this has been discussed [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/multiline-pattern-match-using-sed-awk-or-grep), pcregrep looks the easiest solution.

Comment: This is not possible, based on a review of the source code for `less` (`search.c:search_range()`). The search/match operation is performed on a single newline-delimited line at a time, so you cannot match across line boundaries. See `line.c:forw_raw_line()` for the implementation of "readline" as called by `search_range`.

Comment: Aside, review less release notes for options - Google search site:greenwoodsoftware.com inurl:news

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible to match across line boundaries, because the search function in `less` operates on a single newline-delimited line at a time. This is the case regardless of the system regex implementation (GNU, POSIX, PCRE, etc.).

*Please note that I couldn't find an official source repository for the mainline development of* `less`*, but for purposes of code review here, the links that follow are from the FreeBSD contrib tree.*

See [search.c:search_range()](https://gitorious.org/freebsd/freebsd/source/8f099a01430498291b51d02647ffccc39d83a22a:contrib/less/search.c#L730) for the implementation of the search operation. The loop therein calls [line.c:forw_raw_line()](https://gitorious.org/freebsd/freebsd/source/8f099a01430498291b51d02647ffccc39d83a22a:contrib/less/line.c#L1127) to retrieve the next newline-delimited block of content. That block is passed to [match.c:match_pattern()](https://gitorious.org/freebsd/freebsd/source/f1d6f4778d2044502209708bc167c05f9aa48615:contrib/less/pattern.c#L245) where the search pattern (regular expression) is executed.

To match across multiple lines, you'll need to use a different tool. One option is to drop into your editor and use its search capabilities as suggested by others. You can invoke the editor by pressing `v` in `less`.

Comment: Official source code of _less_ can be found at https://github.com/gwsw/less or http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/download.html#source

Comment: Wow, github page for LESS is under 500 stars. Maybe visit and give the authors credit? Donations?  From there maybe some work on multiline is possible.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure how to do it in `less`, but you can accomplish the same in `vim`.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines

```
/PATTERN1\\_.\\{-}PATTERN2
```

The atom `\\_.` finds any character including end-of-line. The multi `\\{-}` matches as few as possible.

Comment: This does not answer the question, however, since it is about less, not vim. It should be a comment.

Comment: @sashoalm It's still an attempt to answer, so I'd vote it down, and move on. People searching for a solution may not be bound to use one tool specifically.

Answer (score 2):

`less` is using `ed` regex syntax and it does not support multiline matching unfortunately.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/ed-regular-expression-syntax.html#ed-regular-expression-syntax

I was hoping to find that as well, or at least find if this syntax bit was used in `less`:

> RE_DOT_NEWLINE If this bit is set, then the match-any-character
>   operator matches a newline; if this bit isn’t set, then it doesn’t.

So I can use `.+` pattern to match newlines. But no, it doesn't.

Comment: _less is using ed regex syntax_ – that is not true. From `man less`: _The pattern is a regular expression, as recognized by the regular expression library supplied by your system._